# Can I see who I've blocked in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

Is there a page on Twitter where you can view all the users you have blocked (similar to viewing your block list on Facebook)?

Comment: Just to mention, here there is a direct link to Twitter Help Guide: [Blocking people on Twitter](https://support.twitter.com/articles/117063-blocking-people-on-twitter#).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this using Twitter, you can only do this using a 3rd Party Site or App.

Try http://www.twitblock.org/

- click the "more options" link
- then select "Manage your blocks" [direct link](http://www.twitblock.org/blocks)
- You will then need log in to Twitter using the link provided to allow access to your account

Comment: how is that possible? said third-party/app is doing exactly that with twitter's api...thats how they're going to get you the information...i'm assuming....

Comment: @albert https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/blocks/list

Comment: ah, so then you can do it with twitter...

Answer (score 5):

I have created a Twitter tool to view your blocking list on Twitter

[Blocked By Me](http://blockedby.me) will show you a detailed list of all the users you are blocking with an option to unblock any of them.

Comment: This is actually really good. Nice job!

Answer (score 3):

You can now find all blocked accounts on Twitter settings page.

Twitter Official page for "**Accounts you're blocking**"
https://twitter.com/settings/blocked